# How to get the "dirty plus" with hg log --template?

Tags: mercurial

```
hg log -l1 -r . --template {node}
```

Will give you the full changeset hash for your current working directory, but how do I get the `+` on the end to indicate that your copy is dirty (uncomitted changes) like `hg id` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `hg id -i`; if you want the full hash, add `--debug`.  (`hg log` does not examine the work-tree and hence has no idea whether it's dirty.)

Comment: Oh... yeah, I guess that makes sense. "Dirty" is not a concept that applies to past changesets.